# Dim a led using a NPN transistor

Tags: arduino-nano, potentiometer, transistor, analogwrite

I know there are a lot of questions about this topic, but I've tried everything and any possible guide online without success.

I want dim (increase and decrease the brightness) some leds (3.5 Watt each). To do that I'm using an Arduino Nano, a 10k potentiometer and an NPN transistor ([TIP41](http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/2785/MOSPEC/TIP41C/443/3/TIP41C.html)).

I was able to drive the potentiometer as a switch: on/off. Now I want to control its brightness using the potentiometer. I don't get what I'm expecting because the led is always on except when the potentiometer is turned all the way on the right (where is connected Vcc).

This is the schematic:

[image: dim led using transistor npn]

This is my Arduino code:

```
int pinPotentiometer = 0;
int pinTransistor = 3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  pinMode(pinTransistor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinPotentiometer, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int potValue = analogRead(pinPotentiometer);
  int outValue = map(potValue, 0, 1023, 0 ,255);
  Serial.println(outValue);
  digitalWrite(pinTransistor, outValue);
  delay(100);
}
```

The potentiometer is working fine because I read from the serial values between 0 and 255.

Am I using the wrong transistor? Or maybe I'm using it in the wrong way?

**NOTE**: to test my circuit I'm using a small 5mm led and not the 3.5 Watt one so I don't have any external power source.

Many thanks!

Comment: Use `analogWrite()` instead of `digitalWrite()`. And make sure you're using a PWM-capable pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using analogWrite().

Writes an analog value (PWM wave) to a pin. Can be used to light a LED at varying brightnesses or drive a motor at various speeds. After a call to analogWrite(), the pin will generate a steady square wave of the specified duty cycle until the next call to analogWrite() (or a call to digitalRead() or digitalWrite()) on the same pin. The frequency of the PWM signal on most pins is approximately 490 Hz. On the Uno and similar boards, pins 5 and 6 have a frequency of approximately 980 Hz.

Source: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/

Comment: Considering using a protected MOSFET, it will run much cooler then the transistor.  Reason the transistor has a 0.7V collector emitter voltage drop, the MOFET will be less then 0.01 depending on choice. You are missing a resistor from the base to the Nano.  Use something in the 50 to 120 Ohm for the MOSFET to keep it ultra stable. Be sure to use a seperate power supply with the high wattage LEDs. Also connect the power supply grounds.

Comment: @Gil - The OP stated they were using a TIP41 transistor. Perhaps your comment would be useful if you added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

your transistor base should be connected to the PWM side of the Arduino and not the collector. put a 1kOhm resistor between that base and arduino too. collector to load, load to positive of battery or power source. emitter to ground.

Comment: You also need a resistor on the collector side, if the load is a LED. For 3W Led you need a fat resistor (some Watts)